# Struggling to connect my MacBook to my router via ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

I've moved into a newly built house and had the electrician install ethernet ports to run from where our router will be to two other points in the house. Neither of these ethernet ports are working so I'm trying to debug. Here's what's happening:

- If I plug my Mac directly into the router via ethernet it connects to the internet no problem
- If I connect my mac to the wall socket in my office and then from the other end into my router I can't connect and SYstem Preferences says my connection has "a self-assigned IP address and will not be able to connect to the internet.
- The same thing happens from the other ethernet point in my house and I've already tried both connections at the router end to make sure I'm not mixing up the connections
- I've checked the ethernet cables at both ends by using them to connect my computer straight into the router and they work fine

Is it then the case that I have to assume that my electrician wired the in-wall connections incorrectly? (or a builder drilled through the cable?). Or could I be doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong and you know your computer and Modem both work.

Call back the electrician and have the cable connections checked and corrected. It is not likely two cables went bad, but is likely the connections are not good.

This is your electrician's issue to solve even if they need to bring in a qualified technician